# combining separate audio and video files into one file C++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, ffmpeg

I am working on a C++ project with openCV. It is a simple web cam application with basic features like capturing pictures and videos. I have already been able to save video (w/o audio). Since openCV doesnot support audio processing, I was wondering if there is any way I can record audio separately in a different file and later combine those together to get one video file.
While searching on the internet, I did hear something about using ffmpeg with openCV. But I just cant figure out how to do it exactly.....

Can you guys help me? I would be very grateful... Thankyou!

P.S. I have used openCV and QT (for GUI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, opencv doesn't by itself deal with audio. However once you get a separate audio and video file, you can combine them using a technique called [muxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing). There are many many ways to do this. I use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) for most of my muxing needs, although it is windows only (not sure if that's a problem). I know ffmpeg is also capable of muxing (via the command line interface), I can't recall what the command is. There's also mplayer and a multitude of other programs out there to do this.

Comment: Thanks Chris.


I looked into openCV's documentation for using ffmpeg. I did find some commands for muxing. So, will it work if I run those commands from system() function?

Comment: @Aashish Shrestha: as long as the parameters you're passing in to ffmpeg are correct (i.e. you'll want to run it by hand first to double-check) then yes it should work just fine with the `system` command.

Comment: Thanks Chris! You've been a real help! :)

Comment: Not a problem :) If you like the answer make sure to mark it as the official answer using the check mark to the left. Welcome to SO by the way.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know openCV is good for video/image processing. To support audio processing, you can use other libraries e.g. PortAudio or C-sound.