# Merging audio and video files into one [C++]

Tags: c++, audio, video, merge

My C++ application is using openframeworks to record video from webcam in .mov format, and a 3rd party application to record application sound to a separate .wav file.
In the end of the execution I need to merge both video and audio files into one. Is there any library or API that does this?

Would appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: `ffmpeg` is one tool you could look into. There is also `libavcodec` which `ffmpeg` uses. But what you need is only "muxing" (packing the streams into a container), not "encoding". `ffmpeg` can do this but I don't know how (if it uses `libavcodec` for this).

Comment: Just found out that the library which `ffmpeg` uses for muxing is called [`libavformat`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/libavformat.html). It seems to be the solution for this task.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736498/combining-separate-audio-and-video-files-into-one-file-c), the following are quoted from there:

> Once you get a separate audio and video file, you can combine them using a technique called [muxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing). There are many many ways to do this. I use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) for most of my muxing needs, although it is windows only (not sure if that's a problem). I know [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is also capable of muxing (via the command line interface), I can't recall what the command is. There's also mplayer and a multitude of other programs out there to do this.

---

**Edit**: Two ways to use `ffmpeg`:

1. Use `C/C++` API: check out the following great ffmpeg tutorials

   - https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial.
   - https://github.com/phamquy/FFmpeg-tutorial-samples
2. Use system calls:
   check out [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files) for script source code (commands) on how to merge audio and video files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be much to ask for you to show me some code snippet that uses VirtualDub to execute this task?

Comment: Sorry, just now realized you weren't the one that originally wrote that answer! I'll look into it, thanks

Comment: @PedroBatista I think `ffmpeg` is the better choice as `VirtualDub` is a app, maybe not suitable used in `C++`.

Comment: So, to do it in the code I'd have to use system to write ffmpeg command line input, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I have added the link on detailed commands needed to merge audio/video files.

Comment: I've successfully used ffmpeg to merge audio and video, now I need to do it through code. Can you point me to a tutorial for entering command lines through c++ code? thanks

Comment: Try the first way I added in the answer, i.e. use C/C++ API. Much easier.